# How can I clear ehcahe objects in spring configured java project programmatically

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

Now my project need is to trigger the flushing of all active cached objects. Based on all my findings I have written the following code.

```
Collection<String> names = cacheManager.getCacheNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(name);
        cache.put(name, null);
    }
```

Here cacheManger is the object of @Autowired EhCacheCacheManager cacheManager. Even i have tried cache.evict(name); But all these hack doesn't work for me, when it comes for keyed caches.

Yes too i have tried the annotation based envition using following code snippets:

```
 @Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "cache1", allEntries = true), @CacheEvict(value = "cache2", allEntries = true) })
    public static boolean refresh() {
        return true;
    }
```

So the whole point I want to flush all my ehcached cached object.

I got one understanding towards the clearing all the cached, if i could get all the keys then I could flush them by using following code snippet:

```
Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache(nameOfCache);
        if (cache.get(keyOfCache) != null) {
            cache.put(keyOfCache, null);
        }
```

Comment: For the record, you can't use the annotation model on a static method as we create a proxy around the **instance**

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll You are correct as running anti pattern, but for creation of utility function i want to make it static. As of now if you can suggest more holistic design for this, that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Cache.clear()` method.

Take a look at this:  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#clear()

Answer (score 4):

With Spring 4 upwards and Java 8 upwards you can write:

```
cacheManager.getCacheNames().stream()
   .map(cacheManager::getCache)
   .forEach(Cache::clear);
```

This is similar to Przemek Nowaks answer but without the need to use a static `List` method.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Javaslang</strike> Vavr + cache manager:

```
        List.ofAll(cacheManager.getCacheNames())
            .map(cacheManager::getCache)
            .forEach(Cache::clear);
```